# How to sort posts in archive loop

Tags: loop

I need to sort posts using this loop, is an archive page (pc-archive.php) for a CTP named "PC".

Tried with              `<?php while ( have_posts('order=desc') ) : the_post(); ?>`

but no luck... i must be doing something badly.

then I have tried adding this filter, but i dont get it to work...

```
function my_custom_archive_order( $vars ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && isset($vars['post_type']) && is_post_type_hierarchical($vars['post_type']) ) {
    $vars['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
    $vars['order'] = 'DESC';
  }

  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'my_custom_archive_order');
```

this is the loop:

```
             <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="galleryphotos">
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo types_render_field("pcurl", array("raw" => "true")); ?>">
              <img  class="pcimagestyle" src="<?php echo types_render_field("pcimage", array("raw" => "true")); ?>">
</a>       

    <div class="icons">            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo types_render_field("pcurl", array("raw" => "true")); ?>"
                      <ul class="pcitems"> 
        <li><?php the_title(); ?> </li>
              <li>   <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="pcpubname"][/types]'); ?>  </li>     
              <li>   <?php echo do_shortcode('[types field="pcdate" format="d/m/Y"][/types]'); ?></li>
                </ul>
              </a>
</div>
               </div>       <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This filter has to be set in `functions.php`.
Your filter won't work as expected because your condition is wrong.
The condition here imply that you try to order pages (hierarchical post) instead of regular posts-like entries.

You have to be careful using this filter as it has effect on your whole website.

```
function my_custom_archive_order( $vars ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && isset($vars['post_type']) && $vars['post_type'] == 'pc' ) {
    $vars['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
    $vars['order'] = 'DESC'; // you probably don't need this because that's the default behaviour
  }

  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'my_custom_archive_order');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request